# Use variables as a part of a name with loops

Tags: c#

I have a few NumericUpDown objects. I need to save all their values into their corresponding variables (in properties). I have set it with a loop so it's shorter but it does not work.

This is the code:

```
private void RefreshTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)

for (int Count = 11; Count <= 16; Count++)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.("_NW" + Count) = this.Controls.("NW" + Count).Value;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save;
}
```

The long code Should look like this:

```
        Properties.Settings.Default._NW11 = NW11.Value;
        Properties.Settings.Default._NW12 = NW12.Value;
        Properties.Settings.Default._NW13 = NW13.Value;
        Properties.Settings.Default._NW14 = NW14.Value;
        Properties.Settings.Default._NW15 = NW15.Value;
        Properties.Settings.Default._NW16 = NW16.Value;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

but is too much long so i want to use a loop.

What's wrong?

Comment: "it does not work" is not an adequate problem description. Please state exactly what the problem is.

Comment: `Default.("_NW" + Count)` - What is this syntax?

Comment: Properties.Settings.Default._NW + The count value -> this is the syntax to indicate the variable where to put the NumericUpDown value. the NumericUpDown is NW + the count value. Actually i noticed there's some errors in the code because of coping and pasting without rereading (sorry).

Comment: This is the right code: 

private void RefreshTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int Count = 11; Count <= 16; Count++)
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.("_NW" + Count) = this.Controls.("NW" + Count).Value;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }
        }

Comment: @tutorialinformation: If the code in the question needs to be updated, you may want to update it.  It looks like that comment still has that broken syntax though.  If you're trying to compose a property name out of strings, it doesn't work like that.  Maybe instead you can use a `Dictionary` and store the values with string-based keys?

Comment: @David i basically need to compose a name using variables, nothing else, as you can do in VBA.

Comment: @tutorialinformation: Failing the use of a different data structure (such as a `Dictionary`), the only other way I can think of to achieve that kind of functionality is via reflection, which often isn't ideal.  Though I don't really see from the code why this is even necessary.  Why not just invoke the variables directly?  It looks like you're trying to do something very complex in order to save 6 lines of code.  And that complex thing is itself going to be more than 6 lines of code.

Comment: @David Is not only 6 lines, that was only a small part of the entire code, the lines are 48.

I'll search how dictionary works and see if is possible to do in that way. Thank you so much.

Comment: @David ok I'm definitively stupid, i found the problem... The Timer was not enabled...

Answer (score 1):

If you are thinking of resorting to Reflection, always try to find more options.

The solution is Arrays/Lists. They are designed for indexed access, a requirement you're trying to fulfill. But for you to achieve this, you need to restructure your existing resource pointers to be initialized and organized in such an Array/List.

1) For your Settings, use a single System.Collection.Specialized.StringCollection, instead of several individual string settings. Make the first ones empty.

2) Then, setup your controls into an array.

```
List<Control> controlsArray = new List<Control>();
void FormLoad(...)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++)
        controlsArray.Add(null); //Dummy values

    controlsArray.Add(this.Controls.NW11);
    controlsArray.Add(this.Controls.NW12);
    controlsArray.Add(this.Controls.NW13);
    controlsArray.Add(this.Controls.NW14);
    controlsArray.Add(this.Controls.NW15);
    controlsArray.Add(this.Controls.NW16);
}
```

3) Then you can do this:

```
private void RefreshTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int Count = 11; Count <= 16; Count++)
    {
        if (controlsArray[Count] == null)
            continue; //To be on the safe side
        Properties.Settings.Default._NW[Count] = controlsArray[Count].Value;
    }
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save(); //Do this after the assignment loop has finished
}
```

4) If you have many more controls, and need to repeat this pattern often in your coding, then you can automate step [2] better.

```
List<Control> controlsArray = new List<Control>();
void FormLoad(...)
{
    foreach (var control in this.Controls)
    {
        if (control.Name.StartsWith("NW") == false)
            continue;

        var numberString = control.Name.SubString(2, control.Name.Length - 2);
        var controlNumber = int.Parse(numberString);

        while (numberString > controlsArray.Count - 1)
           controlsArray.Add(null);

        controlsArray[controlNumber] = control;
    }
}
```

But for such a small problem, it makes more sense to just use your long solution. Why have all this code (perhaps double the lines, and not as simple to follow what it's doing - and why), when you can just be explicit?

That's up to you to decide.

**Anti-Reflection Rant**

And yes, you should ALWAYS try to avoid reflection.

Even for serialization / deserialization, the answer isn't reflection. You can generate helper functions at compile-time, or even generate serialization proxies during runtime. More work of course, but certainly better. Google's protobuf tools generate code files from protocol files at design-time.

Even for linking to existing libraries. For example, you can use Mono.Cecil, to convert all private interfaces to public at runtime, then reference directly.

I hope you get the point. You don't always have the resources, but it's always the *best* solution when you can avoid Reflection.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has the same problem: The Code Works Just Remind to Enable the timer...

Code:

```
private void RefreshTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int Count = 11; Count <= 16; Count++)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.("_NW" + Count) = this.Controls.("NW" + Count).Value;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection. Something like (not tested):

```
for (int Count = 11; Count <= 16; Count++)
{
    var property = Properties.Settings.Default.GetType().GetProperty("_NW" + Count);
    var value = this.Controls["NW" + Count].Value;
    property.SetValue (Properties.Settings.Default, propertyValue, null);
}

Properties.Settings.Default.Save;
```

Other approaches, carry an dynamic object like an `ExpandoObject` for settings, and then finally save it to `Settings` in one shot later at some point. Also, property setting reflection could be made faster using expression trees.

Comment: Take whatever your control has then. May be `Text`?. Your code has `Value` property, so I used it. Whatever produces `NW11.Value` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I went in another forum and asked the same question and the right code (the most simpliest) is:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int Count = 11; Count <= 16; Count++)
        {
            ((NumericUpDown)(Controls["NW" + Count])).Value = (decimal)Properties.Settings.Default["_NW" + Count];
        }
    }

    private void RefreshTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int Count = 11; Count <= 16; Count++)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default["_NW" + Count] = ((NumericUpDown)(Controls["NW" + Count])).Value;
        }
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
```

This will save the vlaues in the variables and load the values in the NumericUPDown when you load the program (or Form1).